# Postgres SQL Query to fetch email address from string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to postgres have requirement where I need to fetch the email address from string field.There could be multiple email address.
 
Example Input:

```
String
abc-cde-ghi-abc@test.com -cde@test.com
Finance-ddl-sample@yahoo.com-sample1@gmail.com-sample2@msn.com
```

There is no fixed position of '-'

Output:

```
abc@test.com;cde@test.com
sample@yahoo.com;sample1@gmail.com;sample2@msn.com
```

I have tried `substring (string,'[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}')` and able to fetch one email address  but not sure how to fetch multiple email address.Can anyone please help.

Comment: A hyphen is a valid character in email addresses, which makes is a really poor choice for delimiting email addresses.

Comment: @gre_gor - Yes,but in 95%cases hyphen is not coming in email addresses.I am not sure how to write query to fetch multiple email address.Can you pls help

Comment: Use PostgreSQL's regular expression support.

Comment: This absolutely isn't going to work. As said a hyphen is valid within an email address and your examples use this. Splitting out by this character isn't going to work easily. Can you change the structure of the data?

Comment: @Test A single address with "-" could mangle 2 addresses, so you could be getting 10% of invalid addresses. That isn't good at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first say such kind of DB design is a really bad idea and hurts the normalisation rules. Generally, one column should contain one information and not a bunch of mail addresses. Better create a mapping table where all mail addresses for one person are stored separately.

Even if the above improvement is not possible for you for whatever reason, try to find a better separator that indicates the "border" between different mail addresses. I know many people who use a `-` in their mail address, so I doubt you will get what you want this way.

But anyway, it's up to you to deal with those issues. Here is an option to get your expected result:

```
WITH separatedMailAddresses AS
  (SELECT 
    email, 
    UNNEST(
      STRING_TO_ARRAY(email, '-')
    ) AS parts 
   FROM yourtable
   GROUP BY email)
SELECT 
  email,
  REPLACE(STRING_AGG(parts, ',')
  FILTER (WHERE parts LIKE '%@%'),' ','') AS email_list
FROM separatedMailAddresses
GROUP BY email;
```

This will produce the outcome you described in your question. Remove the email column from the second query if you don't want it.

Try out [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/9QVSrybP)

Some explanation what's going on there:

The combination of `UNNEST` and `STRING_TO_ARRAY` is a well-known "workaround" to build up a `SPLIT_PART` function without having to provide a position as argument. The `SPLIT_PART` function requires a string, a separator and the position of the part we want to fetch. But you don't want to fetch a certain part only, but to get all parts between the `-`. As far as I know, this is not possible with a build-in function.

In order to create a comma separated list from the different mail addresses, we can use `STRING_AGG`. But we have to `FILTER` out those "mail addresses" that do not contain the `@` because those strings should not appear in the result. Therefore, we have this condition with `LIKE`.

It's possible that the list of mail addresses we have created now contains spaces (with your sample data, that's actually the case). So we remove them using `REPLACE`.

Comment: Thank you @Jonas..appreciate your help.I have tried most of the sample and its working as expected,however in one case where the value is like 'Marketing - PIN-Batch Process - Customer Insight –  flags_final table – test - F setup – abc@test.com - sample_example@test.com' I am getting the output as Fsetup–abc@test.com,sample_example@test.com.Not sure why its not giving email addresses only.

Comment: @Test That's because you used different characters as separators. My query expects the same separator in all cases. `–` is not the same as `-`. You can use `REPLACE` to make them identic, see https://dbfiddle.uk/Awjde8U-, then you will get the expected result again.

Comment: Thank you @Jonas..you are genius..I agree there might be some false positive but we are trying to follow consistent pattern.

Comment: @Jonas-I am new to this site. I need at least 15 points to mark the answer as best. If you can please mark the question as positive.I may get some points then I can start voting.

Comment: I have marked it as best @Jonas.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Jonas - I have raised another question : I know you are expert in postgres. Can you pls help with different question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78252803/compare-fields-in-two-tables.I can provide any inputs you may require.I am stuck and no idea how to achieve it.Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated.