# Compare fields in two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I would like to write an Update query. I need to update target_table field in tblnames1 based on tblenames2.

**tblNames1**:

| filename | Description | target table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /app/data/shared/mbs/test.yaml | select * from test.fn_hierarchy_prod_group(1); |  |
| /app/data/shared/nkm/test1.yaml | select *from run_update_query |  |
| /app/data/shared/nkm/test5.yaml | select *from func_datad_addr_1 |  |
| /app/data/shared/nkm/test2.yaml | INSERT INTO a_base(evnt_nbr,triggering_evnt,)SELECT evnt_nbr,triggering_evnt FROM delim; |  |

**tblNames2**:

| ID | Description | target table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1082 | test.fn_hierarchy_prod_group | dba.l,dba.z |
| 1091 | func_datad_addr | dba.n |
| 1099 | fn_hierarchy_customer | dba.m |
| 1100 | run_update_query | dba.j |

Output -
scenario 1 : Compare field description of tblnames2 in tblnames1 description field.
Example : Description of tblnames2: test.fn_hierarchy_prod_group exact match present in description of  tblname1 select * from **test.fn_hierarchy_prod_group**(1); then there are 2 targets so populate into 2 different rows i.e one with dba.l and other with dba.z.

Scenario 2:If there is nothing matching in description then check if description in tblnames1 is insert sql example :

```
INSERT INTO **a_base**(evnt_nbr,triggering_evnt,)
  SELECT evnt_nbr,triggering_evnt 
  FROM delim 
then populate target tablename after into clause i.e a_base.
```

**Output :**

| filename | Description | target table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /app/data/shared/mbs/test.yaml | select * from test.fn_hierarchy_prod_group(1); | **dba.l** |
| /app/data/shared/mbs/test.yaml | select * from test.fn_hierarchy_prod_group(1); | **dba.z** |
| /app/data/shared/nkm/test1.yaml | select *from run_update_query | **dba.j** |
| /app/data/shared/nkm/test5.yaml | select *from func_datad_addr_1 |  |
| /app/data/shared/nkm/test2.yaml | INSERT INTO a_base(evnt_nbr,triggering_evnt,)SELECT evnt_nbr,triggering_evnt FROM delim; | **a.base** |

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the SQL you’ve manage to write so far and explain the specific issue you are facing

Comment: @NickW - I have tried the below sql but its not giving me the required output as I am new to postgres.
    select a.filename, a.description, b.target_table
    from tblNames1 a 
    left join tblNames2 b
    on a.description ilike concat('%',b.description,'%');

facing couple of issues here :i) not able to get dba.l,dba.z in seperate lines
 ii)  not able to match exact function pattern like  func_datad_addr_1 with  func_datad_addr 
 iii) In case of Insert INTO statement I need table name in 
target_table that requirement I am not sure how to achieve 
within single query.

Comment: Ok - but please update your question with this information, rather than add it in a comment. If you ensure that your question includes all the latest information then someone reading it can more easily understand what you are asking. If you add information in comments then someone has to go through your question and comments and try and work out what information is current and what has been superseded. Also, text in the question can be formatted - so it is easier to read

Comment: Just as an FYI, you are highly unlikely to be able to execute a SQL statement held in a column in a table (which appears to be one of the things you are trying to do) without using dynamic SQL